# Drop last section of string in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, path, split, trim

I have found many ways in Powershell to capture the sections of strings using `split()`, but I am stumped on this one. Using the example string below:

```
"Monkey/Zebra/Bird/Bird"
```

I am able to capture the end "Bird" using the code below:

```
$path = "Monkey/Zebra/Bird/Bird"

$animal = $path.split("/")[-1]
```

My end goal is to be able to capture the front of the string, without the last "split", so to output:

```
"Monkey/Zebra/Bird"
```

The number of "Animals" will vary, so I cannot hard code the number of characters or "/" to look for.

Answer (score 4):

Using a regular expression with -replace:

```
$text = "Monkey/Zebra/Bird/Bird"

$text -replace '/[^/]+$'

Monkey/Zebra/Bird
```

Comment: This is very elegant, but it would help to have an explanation of the regex, so that people understand why it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a regex too, but if you wanted to use a split:

```
("Monkey/Zebra/Bird/Bird" -split '/')[0..((("Monkey/Zebra/Bird/Bird" -split '/').count)-2)] -join '\'
```

I love Perl...errr Powershell

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for each command such as

```
$path = "Monkey/Zebra/Bird/Bird"
foreach($animal in $path.split("/"))
{
Write-Host $animal
}
```

This will then split the path and process each animal in turn

Answer (score 0):

I preface this with the fact that RegEx is probably your fastest answer. That said...

Another approach, using split, to get only one of each animal since your example was parsing out the duplicate "bird" from "Monkey/Zebra/Bird/Bird"

```
$Animals = "Monkey/Zebra/Bird/Bird"

($Animals.Split('/')|Select -Unique) -join '/'
```

Or if you just want to drop the last part you can do what EBGreen suggested, split it into individual animals, count those, return all but the last one, and re-join them together.

```
($Animals.Split('/'))[0..($Animals.Split('/').count-2)] -join '/'
```

Either of those will return `Monkey/Zebra/Bird` but if you like the latter of the options please attribute the answer to EBGreen.

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = "Monkey/Zebra/Bird/Bird"
$path -replace '/\w+$'
Monkey/Zebra/Bird
```